# Custom child commands for UI elements

Tags: cypress

We're currently using Select2 for all our `<select>` elements and for obvious reasons `cy.get("#element").select("foo")` won't work. As per the docs we've created our own custom command `cy.get("#element").select2("foo")` which just wraps a number of steps to select "foo".

This works well when trying to select a value but we'd like to avoid adding custom commands for clear(), value(), etc.

We'd also like to avoid using the Select2 API because this would require someone to understand that API as opposed to just working in the Cypress API.

We'd like to create something a bit more flexible by instead having a Cypress friendly object. Something that would look like this:

```
cy.get("#element").select2().as("select2");
cy.get("@select2").select("foo");
cy.get("@select2").should("be.equal", "foo");
cy.get("@select2").clear();
```

Is it possible to create a child-command that returns an object that can then override these built in commands?

We're unable to return our custom object from our custom command without first `cy.wrap`ing it which defeats the purpose.

Comment: What's the error you have when returning the object?  I am doing something similar with custom commands returning objects, then chaining other default cypress commands off of that.

Comment: @Brendan i get this: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages.html#Cypress-detected-that-you-invoked-one-or-more-cy-commands-in-a-custom-command-but-returned-a-different-value

Comment: Ah that's pretty easy to overcome.  You need to return the entire chain of cy commands from the custom command.  If you post your non-working custom command I can show you what I mean